# Adding LaunchScreen.storyboard change the size of UIScreen.mainScreen

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, storyboard, launch-screen

I have an iPad app that works only on a Landscape Full-Screen mode and does not use a *LaunchScreen.storyboard*.

When `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called, the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` always returns (0,0,1024,768), which is great.

When adding a *LaunchScreen.storyboard*, the size of the screen on `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is changed to:
(0,0,1366,1024) in iPad Pro, and to
(0,0,1112,834) on iPad Air 3rd generation.

Why does it change, and how can I avoid this?